# DropDownList not population from SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms

I am missing something.  I am trying to populate a drop down list from a table in a SQL database.  I have several columns in the table but only want 2, 1 for value and 1 for text based on the value that is entered from a textbox.  My test page I just gave the session variable a value from my table.  I have test my SQL connection and varified that works.  I have tested my select statement in SQL and varified that I received only the data that I want.

Can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong.

the drop down list is a simple asp DDL:

```
<asp.DropDownList ID="DD1" runat="server"></asp.DropDownList>
```

The code behind is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string a = Session["Test"] as string;
   string IDSel = "SELECT Value, Text FROM DDL1 WHERE Value = '@Value'";
   SqlConnection IDcon = new SqlConnection(connection string);
   IDcon.Open();
   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(IDSel, IDcon);
   adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", a);
   DataSet IDds = new DataSet();
   adapter.Fill(IDds);
   try
   {
      DD1.DataSource = IDds;
      DD1.DataTextField = "Text";
      DD1.DataValueField = "Value";
      DD1.DataBind();
   }
   catch
   {
      Response.Write("No data found");
   }
   IDcon.Close();
}
```

My master page has the:

```
    Session["Test"] = //a value from my table
```

I have added

```
Response.Write(a);
```

at different points and I get the table value displayed where I expected it and I never received no data found.
1 example I found had me add

```
DD1.BindData();
```

right after the `DD1.DataSource` line but that caused error messages about my parameter value. I have ran debug and it runs clean.

Comment: you need to access the dataset's tables... IDds.Tables[0] should be your datasource. If you are reading from one table and getting one table back why not just use a datatable instead of a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your parameter placeholder between single quotes it will be treated as a string literal, not as a parameter

```
string IDSel = "SELECT Value, [Text] FROM DDL1 WHERE Value = @Value";
```

Also to avoid possible confusion with the reserved keyword I think you need to put the word TEXT between square brackets

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
DD1.DataSource = IDds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist, but did not resolve the issue.  See Steves answer below.

Answer (score 1):

its an correct way to add sql parameters

```
 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Value", a);
```

and

```
string IDSel = "SELECT Value, Text FROM DDL1 WHERE Value = @Value";
```